# Isin function skip correct value python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filtering, isin

I am working with a response json file from a get API request. I have been able to figure out how to flatten the response and I want to filter the related dataframe by records containing pdf file extension only that I the will use to retrieve the files of interest.
This is the code:

```
from flatten_json import flatten
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
payload= {"chamber_type":"committee","chamber":"dail","date_start":"2018-01-01", "date_end":"2018-12-31", "limit":"1000"}
test = requests.get("https://api.oireachtas.ie/v1/debates", params=payload)
text = test.content.decode("utf-8")
print(text)
test.json()
test1=flatten(test.json())
df = pd.Series(test1).to_frame()
df[["pdf"]] = df[df.index.isin(["uri_pdf"])]
```

The entire df returns nan even when it should give a positive result.
[image]

I have tried to filter the index by the same expression but the result is an empty df.

Where isin is not working here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.isin() does not work as you probably expect it (e.g. contains). IIUC, you need str.contains():

```
df[df.index.str.contains('pdf_uri')]
```

or in your case you can use str.endswith()

```
df[df.index.str.endswith('pdf_uri')]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Danail, have you tried it to check if it works? In my case it does not. Either because "index" is not defined and even when I iterate over df.index as initially posted.

Comment: What do you get if you simply do `df[df['Index'].str.endswith("uri_pdf")]` ? I did put 'Index' as I've seen in your output that the column name is with capital `I`.

Comment: Index is actually the index of the dataframe not a column that is why the output is :

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: 'Index'

Comment: It definitely works for me. `df[df.index.str.contains('pdf_uri')]`

Comment: Your solution ended up working for me after some adjustments. No I understand that Isin works with exact matching and ```str.contains``` is more appropriate to search for bits within a string.